# jquery json error, when i want to get json from steam market

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

---

I have a problem with ajax request to Steam.
I want to get price from steam market.

```
function jPrice(httpToJson) {
    $.getJSON(httpToJson, function(data) {
        return data.median_price;
    });
}
```

When I call function

```
jPrice('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29');
```

I get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P250%20%7C%20Steel%20Disruption%20%28Factory%20New%29. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://lоcalhоst:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

I try:

- Set php header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *
- JSONP

**RESULT -> The same thing (error)!**

Maybe someone knows a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get the results in your browser via ajax request made directly against steamcommunity.com, neither by setting the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *, nor by sending a JSONP request.

For this to work, steamcommunity.com should either add [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers in the response (the error message you're seing means that they are not there), or format the output to be [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). They didn't do either.

This is a browser restriction, do not allow the content from a different origin to be loaded via ajax. What you need to do is introduce a middle-ware, so have your back-end server to make a request against steamcommunity.com and return the same response, and make the ajax call against you're server. This will work, your back-end is sending the request, and as it is not a browser request, the response will land, than your ajax call will be able to get the response as well since it is issued against the same domain

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I try one more time to set CORS.
I search php script [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18399709)
When i reload server and browser on page derived "You have CORS!"
But when i try to get ajax request => same error :(

Comment: you welcome. The problem is that their server didn't configure CORS. What the post is describing is the way you would configure you server to support cross-origin requests. What you should do instead is make a PHP script that sends the request you were sending from ajax, and return the response. And than, from your ajax target your page