# jquery.form file upload works on local system but not on the server - blank page displayed after submit on server

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, ajaxform

I used jquery.form plugin for file upload (downloaded code from http://malsup.com/). It works fine on my local machine but shows blank page after submitting the form on the server. I've set up file permissions 777 for the directory where files are to be uploaded. The "out of the box" code works fine on server. However, I've incorporated it into my jquery mobile setup and added database operations and file-delete forms. While it works as intended locally it displays blank page on the server. There's no error of any kind displayed, files are not getting uploaded, database is not being updated. It appears that the processing code is not executed at all. I have tried to echo something at the start of form processing code and that is not happening either, so it looks like the ajax form does not get submitted.

Here is the code for the form and second for the processing.

```
<?php
    require_once ("lib/required.php");
    $_SESSION['login_data'] = get_login_data();

    # Login Protected Page - send them back home
    if (!$_SESSION['login_data']['user_logged_in']){ # not logged in
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;                       
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # must be logged in - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif ($_SESSION['login_data']['group_title'] != 'Landlord'){ # logged in but not a Landlord
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;                       
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id mismatch - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['memid']) && $_GET['memid'] != $_SESSION['login_data']['id']){ # logged in but memid in url is no match (typed in?)
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;                       
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id mismatch - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['propid'])){ 
        if (!$foo = sql_get_results_array("SELECT * FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property WHERE property_id = " . $_GET['propid'] . " AND landlord_id = " . $_GET['memid'])){ # logged in but propid in url is no match (typed in?)
            $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;                       
            header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id vs property mismatch - send them to homepage
            exit;
        }
    }

    # DO NOT include the code below on PayPalP Pay Subscription Page
    # This code MUST BE INCLUDED on every Login Protected Page
    # check subscription and send them to PayPal if not valid
    if (!valid_subscription($_SESSION['login_data']['id'],$_SESSION['login_data']['membership_expiry'],$_SESSION['login_data']['grace_expiry'],$_SESSION['login_data']['subscription_fee'])){ 
        $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 37; # this is to popup a "final call" message
        $redirect_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . "/" . PAYPAL_PAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PAGE . "?memid=" . $_SESSION['login_data']['id'];
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # send them to referring page where resulting messages will be displayed
        exit;
    }
    # DO NOT include the code above on PayPalP Pay Subscription Page

# End-of-Housekeeping

    if (isset($_GET['memid'])){
        $member_id = $_GET['memid']; # get landlord id from url
    } else {
        $member_id = $_SESSION['login_data']['id']; # get landlord id from login        
    }

    if (isset($_GET['propid'])){ # this is for when coming from property details page with a selected property id in url
        $property_id = $_GET['propid']; # get property id from url
        $my_post_list['property-list-form-submitted'] = "1"; # fake "list" form submission to force appropriate form contents
        $my_post_list['property-list'] = $property_id;
        $property_selected = TRUE;
    }

    if ($_POST['property-list-form-submitted'] == "1") { # form submitted - property selected - copy $_POST to own array
        $my_post_list = $_POST;
        if ($my_post_list['property-list'] == 0){ # insert new data - redirect to property details page
            $redirect_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . "/" . LANDLORD_PROPERTY_DETAILS_PAGE . "?memid=" . $_SESSION['login_data']['id'] . "&action=addprop";
            header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # send them to property details page
            exit;
        } else {
            $property_id = $my_post_list['property-list'];
            $property_selected = TRUE;
        }
    }

    $property_list  = sql_get_results_array( "SELECT * FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property WHERE landlord_id = " . $member_id); # get list of all properties & details for this landlord in 2-dimensional associative array

    if ($my_post_list['property-list-form-submitted'] == "1") { # form submitted - property selected - display all property details
        $property_selected = TRUE;
        $property_data  = sql_get_results_array( "SELECT * FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property WHERE landlord_id = " . $member_id . " AND property_id = " . $my_post_list['property-list']);

    }

    if ($_POST['remove-pic-form-submitted'] == "1"){ # delete saved image that was clicked upon

        if (!db("DELETE FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property_picture WHERE property_id = " . $property_id . " AND landlord_id = '" . $member_id . "' AND picture_path = '" . $_POST['remove-this-path'] . "' AND picture_filename = '" . $_POST['remove-this-file'] . "'")){ # delete didn't work
            $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 14; # this is to popup error message if delete fails
        } # /if

        $propimage = $_POST['remove-this-path'] . $_POST['remove-this-file'];
        // See if it exists before attempting deletion on it
        if (file_exists($propimage)) {
            unlink($propimage); // Delete now
        } 
        // See if it exists again to be sure it was removed
        if (file_exists($propimage)) {
            echo "Problem deleting " . $propimage;
        }

        $propthumb = $_POST['remove-this-path'] . "thumb_" . $_POST['remove-this-file'];
        // See if it exists before attempting deletion on it
        if (file_exists($propthumb)) {
            unlink($propthumb); // Delete now
        } 
        // See if it exists again to be sure it was removed
        if (file_exists($propthumb)) {
            echo "Problem deleting " . $propthumb;
        }
    } # /if file delete form submitted

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title ;?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <?php include("inc/pl_css.inc"); ?>
    <link href="css/image-upload.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <?php include("inc/pl_js.inc"); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        //elements
        var progressbox         = $('#progressbox'); //progress bar wrapper
        var progressbar         = $('#progressbar'); //progress bar element
        var statustxt           = $('#statustxt'); //status text element
        var submitbutton        = $("#SubmitButton"); //submit button
        var myform              = $("#UploadForm"); //upload form
        var output              = $("#output"); //ajax result output element
        var completed           = '0%'; //initial progressbar value
        var FileInputsHolder    = $('#AddFileInputBox'); //Element where additional file inputs are appended
        var MaxFileInputs       = 10; //Maximum number of file input boxes

        // adding and removing file input box
        var i = $("#AddFileInputBox div").size() + 1;
        $("#AddMoreFileBox").click(function () {
                event.returnValue = false;
                if(i < MaxFileInputs)
                {
                    $('<span><input type="file" id="fileInputBox" size="20" name="file[]" class="addedInput" value=""/><a href="#" class="removeclass small2"><img src="img/close_icon.gif" border="0" /></a></span>').appendTo(FileInputsHolder);
                    i++;
                }
                return false;
        });

        $("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){
                event.returnValue = false;
                if( i > 1 ) {
                        $(this).parents('span').remove();i--;
                }

        }); 

        $("#ShowForm").click(function () {
          $("#uploaderform").slideToggle(); //Slide Toggle upload form on click
        });

        $(myform).ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
                submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
                statustxt.empty();
                progressbox.show(); //show progressbar
                progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
                statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
                statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text

            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
                progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
                statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
                if(percentComplete>50)
                    {
                        statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
                    }else{
                        statustxt.css('color','#000');
                    }

                },
            complete: function(response) { // on complete
                output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
                myform.resetForm();  // reset form
                submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
                progressbox.hide(); // hide progressbar
                $("#uploaderform").slideUp(); // hide form after upload
            }
        });

        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

<!-- property-images-page -->
   <div data-role="page" id="property-details-page" class="globalpage" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>"> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> function loadPage(url){document.location.href = url;};</script>

        <!-- this .inc file contains 5 panels: login/forgot/register/reset/profile - <div>s with data-role="panel" are inside this file -->
            <?php include("inc/pl_user_options_panel.inc"); ?>
        <!-- /user-options-panel -->        

        <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
            <?php include("inc/pl_menu_panel.inc"); ?>
        </div><!-- /menu-panel -->      

        <!-- top header, non-scrolling, shows two action buttons on sides & user data in the middle -->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <?php include("inc/pl_data_role_header.inc"); ?>
        </div> <!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <!-- page load popup handler -->      
            <?php include("inc/pl_popup_handler.inc"); ?>
            <!-- scrolling page header with PeterLandlord logo -->
            <?php include("inc/pl_page_header.inc");?>

            <div class="formbox">
            <?php # property selection form ?>
            <form name="property-list-form" class="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="property-list-form-submitted" value="1"/>
                <div id="property-list-div" class="ui-field-contain">
                    <label for="property-list" class="<?php echo $message['msg_class'];?>"><b></label>
<?php 
                if ($my_post_list['property-list-form-submitted'] != "1" || sizeof($property_data) == 0) { # form not submitted
?>
                    <select name="property-list" id="property-list" data-native-menu="false" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true"><?php echo get_contents(600); ?></option>
                        <option value="0"><?php echo get_contents(601); ?></option>
<?php
                } else { # form submitted
?>
                    <select name="property-list" id="property-list" data-native-menu="false" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<?php 
                    if ($my_post_list['property-list'] != "0") { # an existing property selected
?>          
                        <option value="<?php echo($my_post_list['property-list']);?>"><?php echo get_contents(602); ?> 
<?php 
                            echo 
                            $property_data[0]['address_line'].", ".
                            $property_data[0]['address_locality'].", ".
                            $property_data[0]['address_state'].", ".
                            $property_data[0]['address_postcode'];
                            $skip_this_property = $property_data[0]['property_id'];
?>
                        </option>
<?php 
                    } # /if an existing property selected
?>
                        <option value="0"><?php echo get_contents(601); ?></option>
<?php
                } # /else
            if ($my_post_list['property-list-form-submitted'] == "1" && $my_post_list['property-list'] == "0") { # add new property selected
                # do nothing
            } else { # display remaining properties
                for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($property_list); $i++){
                    if ($property_list[$i]['property_id'] != $skip_this_property){ # Don't display selected property in the list - it is displayed above 
?>          
                        <option value="<?php echo $property_list[$i]['property_id'];?>">
<?php 
                            echo 
                            $property_list[$i]['address_line'].", ".
                            $property_list[$i]['address_locality'].", ".
                            $property_list[$i]['address_state'].", ".
                            $property_list[$i]['address_postcode'];
?>
                        </option>
<?php
                    } # /if add new property selected
                } # /for
            } # /if Don't display selected property
?>          
                        </select>
                    </div> <!-- /property-list-div -->
                </form> <!-- /property-list-form -->
            </div> <!-- formbox for property selection-->
<?php 
        if ($property_selected){ # only show stored images & image upload form if property is selected

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property_picture WHERE property_id = " . $property_id . " AND  landlord_id = " . $member_id;
            if (!($property_pics = sql_get_results_array($sql))){
                $no_images = TRUE;
            } else {
                $no_images = FALSE;
            }
?>          
            <div class="formbox">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
<?php 
            if ($no_images){
?>
                <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo PROPERTY_IMG_FOLDER ;?>noimages.png" alt="Thumbnail" width="100" height="100"></td>
<?php 
            } else {
                for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($property_pics); $i++){
                    list($ImageWidth,$ImageHeight)=getimagesize($property_pics[$i]['picture_path'] . $property_pics[$i]['picture_filename']);
?>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="#popup<?php echo $i;?>" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn-<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>"><img src="<?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_path'];?><?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_thumbname'];?>" alt="Thumbnail<?php echo $i;?>" height="100px" width="100px"></a>
                        <br>
                        <form name="delete-form-<?php echo $i;?>" id="delete-form-<?php echo $i;?>" class="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>&propid=<?php echo $property_id;?>" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="remove-pic-form-submitted" value="1"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="remove-this-path" value="<?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_path'];?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="remove-this-file" value="<?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_filename'];?>"/>
                            <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('delete-form-<?php echo $i;?>').submit()" class="ui-corner-all ui-btn ui-shadow ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-inline""></a>
                        </form>
                    </td>

                    <div data-role="popup" id="popup<?php echo $i;?>" class="ui-content" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>" style="max-width:1000px;">
                        <a href="#" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
                        <p class="txtcopyright"><img src="<?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_path'];?><?php echo $property_pics[$i]['picture_filename'];?>" alt="Image<?php echo $i;?>" width="<?php echo $ImageWidth;?>" height="<?php echo $ImageHeight;?>"></p>
                    </div>
<?php 
                } # /for
            } # /if no images
?>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div> <!-- formbox for image display-->

            <div class="formbox">
                <div id="uploaderform">
                    <form action="<?php echo LANDLORD_PROPERTY_IMAGES_PROCESS;?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>&propid=<?php echo $property_id;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm">
                        <input type="hidden" name="max-to-upload" value="<?php echo 10 - sizeof($property_pics);?>"/>
                        <h1>Property image file upload</h1>
                        <p>Up to 10 images can by added with each image file size less than 1MB!</p>

                        <label>Images
                        <span class="small"><a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox">Add More Images</a></span>
                        </label>
                        <div id="AddFileInputBox"><input id="fileInputBox" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="file"  name="file[]"/></div>
                        <div class="sep_s"></div>

                        <button type="submit" class="button" id="SubmitButton">Upload</button>

                        <div id="progressbox"><div id="progressbar"></div ><div id="statustxt">0%</div ></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="uploadResults">
                    <div align="center" style="margin:20px;"><a href="#" id="ShowForm">Toggle Upload Form</a></div>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- formbox -->
<?php 
        } # /if property selected
?>          
            <div class="formbox">
                <hr>
                <table class="fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <td><button onClick="loadPage('<?php echo LANDLORD_PROPERTY_DETAILS_PAGE;?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>&propid=<?php echo $property_id;?>');" data-rel="external" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-action"><?php echo get_contents(618)?></button></td>
                        <td>
<?php                       if ($property_selected){ # only show this button if property is selected ?>
                                <button type="reset" onClick="loadPage('<?php echo LANDLORD_PROPERTY_IMAGES_FORM;?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>&propid=<?php echo $property_id;?>');" data-rel="external" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Refresh View</button>
<?php                       }?>
                        </td>
                        <td><button onClick="loadPage('<?php echo LANDLORD_PROPERTY_FEATURES_PAGE;?>?memid=<?php echo $member_id;?>&propid=<?php echo $property_id;?>');" data-rel="external" data-theme="<?php echo $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'];?>" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-action"><?php echo get_contents(609)?></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div> <!-- formbox2 -->
        </div> <!-- /role-main -->  

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <?php include("inc/pl_page_footer.inc"); ?>
        </div> <!-- /footer --> 
    </div>
<!-- /property-images-page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Form processing code:

```
<?php
# pl_landlord_property_img_upl_proc.php

# Housekeeping
    require_once ("lib/required.php");
    $_SESSION['login_data'] = get_login_data();

    # Login Protected Page - send them back home
    if (!$_SESSION['login_data']['user_logged_in']){ # not logged in
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # must be logged in - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif ($_SESSION['login_data']['group_title'] != 'Landlord'){ # logged in but not a Landlord
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id mismatch - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['memid']) && $_GET['memid'] != $_SESSION['login_data']['id']){ # logged in but memid in url is no match (typed in?)
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id mismatch - send them to homepage
        exit;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['propid'])){
        if (!$foo = sql_get_results_array("SELECT * FROM " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property WHERE property_id = " . $_GET['propid'] . " AND landlord_id = " . $_GET['memid'])){ # logged in but propid in url is no match (typed in?)
            $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;
            header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id vs property mismatch - send them to homepage
            exit;
        } else {
            # go through...
        }
    } else {
        $redirect_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . '/' . HOME_PAGE;
        header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # id mismatch - send them to homepage
        exit;
    }

    # DO NOT include the code below on PayPalP Pay Subscription Page
    # This code MUST BE INCLUDED on every Login Protected Page
    # check subscription and send them to PayPal if not valid
    if (!valid_subscription($_SESSION['login_data']['id'],$_SESSION['login_data']['membership_expiry'],$_SESSION['login_data']['grace_expiry'],$_SESSION['login_data']['subscription_fee'])){
            $_SESSION['popup_msg_id'] = 37; # this is to popup a "final call" message
            $redirect_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . APPLICATION_FOLDER . "/" . PAYPAL_PAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PAGE . "?memid=" . $_SESSION['login_data']['id'];
            header ( "Location: " . $redirect_url ); # send them to referring page where resulting messages will be displayed
            exit;
    }
    # DO NOT include the code above on PayPalP Pay Subscription Page

# End-of-Housekeeping

    $member_id = $_GET['memid'];
    $property_id = $_GET['propid'];

    // If you face any errors, increase values of "post_max_size", "upload_max_filesize" and "memory_limit" as required in php.ini

 //Some Settings
    $ThumbSquareSize        = 100; //Thumbnail will be 100x100
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 1000; //Image Maximum height or width
    $ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
    $DestinationDirectory   = PROPERTY_IMG_FOLDER; //Upload Directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 90;

    //ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); // maximum memory!

    foreach($_FILES as $file){
        // some information about image we need later.
        $ImageName      = $file['name'];
        $ImageSize      = $file['size'];
        $TempSrc        = $file['tmp_name'];
        $ImageType      = $file['type'];


        if (is_array($ImageName)){
            $c = count($ImageName);
            echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">';
            echo '<tr>';
            if ($_POST['max-to-upload'] < 0){
                $max_to_upload = 0;
            } else {
                $max_to_upload = $_POST['max-to-upload'];
            }           
            for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++){
                if ($max_to_upload == 0){ 
                    echo '<div class="error">Only 10 files in total allowed!<br>Delete some to upload more.</div>';
                    break;
                }
                $max_to_upload--;
                $processImage = true;   

                if(!isset($ImageName[$i]) || !is_uploaded_file($TempSrc[$i])){
                    echo '<div class="error">Error occurred while trying to process <strong>'.$ImageName[$i].'</strong>, may be file too big!</div>'; //output error
                } else {
                    //Validate file + create image from uploaded file.
                    switch(strtolower($ImageType[$i]))
                    {
                        case 'image/png':
                            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefrompng($TempSrc[$i]);
                            break;
                        case 'image/gif':
                            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromgif($TempSrc[$i]);
                            break;
                        case 'image/jpeg':
                        case 'image/pjpeg':
                            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($TempSrc[$i]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            $processImage = false; //image format is not supported!
                    }
                    //get Image Size
                    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc[$i]);

                    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
                    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName[$i], strrpos($ImageName[$i], '.'));
                    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

                    //Construct a new image name (with time plus counter) for our new image.
                    $NewImageName = $member_id . $property_id . time()+$i . '.' . $ImageExt;

                    //Set the Destination Image path with Random Name
                    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumb name
                    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; //Name for Big Image

                    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
                    if($processImage && resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType[$i])){
                        //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
                        if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType[$i])){
                            echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
                        } # /if !cropImage
                        /*
                        At this point we have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
                        We can render image to user's browser and/or store information in the database
                        */

                        //Get New Image Size
                        list($ResizedWidth,$ResizedHeight)=getimagesize($DestRandImageName);
                        echo '<td align="center"><a href="' . PROPERTY_IMG_FOLDER . $NewImageName . '" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn-' . $_SESSION['login_data']['data_theme'] . '"><img src="' . PROPERTY_IMG_FOLDER . $ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName . '" alt="Thumbnail" height="100px" width="100px"></a></td>';
                        // Insert info into database table
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . DBPREFIX . "tbl_property_picture (property_id,landlord_id,picture_path,picture_filename,picture_thumbname)
                                VALUES (" . $property_id . "," . $member_id . ",'" . PROPERTY_IMG_FOLDER . "','" . $NewImageName . "','" . $ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName . "')";
                        if (!db($sql)){
                            echo '<div class="error">Error inserting into database</div>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<div class="error">Error occurred while trying to process <strong>'.$ImageName[$i].'</strong>! Please check if file is supported</div>'; //output error
                    } # /if $processImage && resizeImage
                } # /else (!isset($ImageName[$i]) || !is_uploaded_file($TempSrc[$i]))
            } # /for
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</table>';
        } # /is_array($ImageName
    } # /foreach    

// This function will proportionally resize image 
    function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
    {
        //Check Image size is not 0
        if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Construct a proportional size of new image
        $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight); 
        $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
        $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);

        if($CurWidth < $NewWidth || $CurHeight < $NewHeight)
        {
            $NewWidth = $CurWidth;
            $NewHeight = $CurHeight;
        }
        $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);
        // Resize Image
        if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
        {
            switch(strtolower($ImageType))
            {
                case 'image/png':
                    imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                    break;
                case 'image/gif':
                    imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                    break;          
                case 'image/jpeg':
                case 'image/pjpeg':
                    imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            if(is_resource($NewCanves)) { 
              imagedestroy($NewCanves); 
            } 
            return true;
        }
    }

//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
    function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
    {    
        //Check Image size is not 0
        if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0){
            return false;
        }

        //abeautifulsite.net has excellent article about "Cropping an Image to Make Square"
        //http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/08/cropping-an-image-to-make-square-thumbnails-in-php/
        if($CurWidth>$CurHeight){
            $y_offset = 0;
            $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
            $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
        } else {
            $x_offset = 0;
            $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
            $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
        } # /else

        $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize); 
        if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size)){
            switch(strtolower($ImageType)){
                case 'image/png':
                    imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                    break;
                case 'image/gif':
                    imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                    break;          
                case 'image/jpeg':
                case 'image/pjpeg':
                    imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            } # /switch

            if(is_resource($NewCanves)) { 
              imagedestroy($NewCanves); 
            } # /if is_resource
            return true;

        } # /if imagecopyresampled
    } # /function

?>
```

Can somebody please point me towards a solution, thanks...

Comment: Have you checked the Browsers console? Do you see any GET or POST errors, usually in Red. It may be a CORS issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS . which in that case you need see this answer to add the header controls to your PHP file. -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382740/cors-not-working-php. or you can download this extension for Chrome to disable CORS. -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: I do not make cross-domain requests so it's not a CORS issue, I think. There are 3 errors shown in Chrome's console. Two are identical on both local and server but one is only present on server where things are not working.

Comment: * Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  - pl_landlord_property_img_upl_frm.php:57
* Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS - 
http://peterlandlord.com.au/test/pl_landlord_property_img_upl_frm.php?memid=11 
* GET http://peterlandlord.com.au/test/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.map 404 (Not Found) - 
/test/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.map:1

Comment: The "Uncaught..." error is the one shown on the server but not locally. This is the only difference between the two environments that I can see so that may be the culprit. It seems to relate to jquery function `$(myform).ajaxForm`

Comment: @Tasos - this comment is just to alert Tasos to my previous comments.

Comment: @Tasos - Solved! I did a search on _Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function_ and some suggested to try not to use **min** javascripts. I've changed that and it now works, which is good but I don't understand how this has made the difference between local environment and the server.

Comment: ok. im not sure why either, but its the norm to use the minified versions of js