# AngularJS: $http service GET to php server: Request Method:OPTIONS, Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angularjs, get, angular-http

I'm struggling with this issue since many hours... :-(

My grunt-served angular app issues an $http **GET** request to a simple PHP service on the same host (apache), to get a list of persons. The result I get is an OPTIONS request (???), which gets a 405 response... But why an OPTIONS pre-flight request before a GET???

These are the details of my setup:

Grunt config *Gruntfile.js*:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  ...
  connect: {
    options: {
      port: 9000,
      hostname: '0.0.0.0',
      livereload: 35729
    },
  },
  ...
```

Angular service *persons.js*:

```
app.service('Persons', function($http) {
  ...
  return({
    getPersons: function () {
      return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: http://192.168.1.1/myapp/api/persons/get',
      }).then(handleSuccess, handleError);
    },
    ...
  });
  ...
```

File */api/persons/get/index.php*:

```
...
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.1.1:9000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
echo json_encode($persons);
```

(I*n fact, server-side I use Slim framework, so this is "index.php" file, which serves "/api/persons/..." requests via .htaccess: "... RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]"...*)

And this is the (sad :-() result I get:

```
Remote Address:192.168.1.1:80
Request URL:http://192.168.1.1/myapp/api/persons/get
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,it-IT;q=0.6,it;q=0.4,tr;q=0.2,de;q=0.2
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.1
Origin:http://192.168.1.1:9000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://192.168.1.1:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Allow:GET HEAD
Connection:close
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 11:36:43 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=a5dbcfa18fcb64a29dbad999c6811d69; path=/
Set-Cookie:a5dbcfa18fcb64a29dbad999c6811d69=DEFAULT%7C0%7C2M3TMlgUx3gTlaarYzHIdD28l8q9FTcNubt55%2BUGpAo%3D%7C7456bf61db3500c8bb7b3bc38082a470ce4a2ad3; path=/
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.4
```

I did also try using `grunt-connect-proxy`, with no better results...

If I forgot any detail, please just ask...

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CORS preflight is mandatory for cross domain request.

The OPTIONS call actually return the list of available method (GET, POST, etc..).

You should allow the OPTIONS call on your php backend :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
```

See there [CORS not working php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382740/cors-not-working-php)

Comment: GREAT! THANKS!!! I love you, man :-) The link you gave saved my day... But, CORS preflight is mandatory even for GET requests? I have to read CORS specifications again ... :-(

Comment: :) I'm not sure it is mandatory either, but maybe it depends of the client sending the request.