# XMLHttpRequest No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to make a login access with ionic 2 and angular 2.
whenever I press the right details I get this error

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://adirzoari.16mb.com/newapi.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.'
> ```

I have also read some similar question on the website and still didn't get any solution for it.

this is my php file of login

```
        <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $conn = new mysqli("mysql.hostinger.co.uk", "a", "1234", "appd");

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382740/cors-not-working-php
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
        }

        // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

            exit(0);
        }


        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        if (isset($postdata)) {
            $request = json_decode($postdata);
            $username = $request->username;
            $password = $request->password;
                    $data = array();

            if ($password != "" && $username != "") {

            //echo "Server returns: " . $username . "Password is :" . $password;

                /*$arr=array();

                $st="select * from subnews order by SubID desc limit 10";
                $qr=$conn->query($st);
                while($row=$qr->fetch_assoc()){
                    $arr[]=$row;
                }
                echo json_encode($arr);*/

                $sel="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                $result=$conn->query($sel);
                $numrow=$result->num_rows;
                if($numrow == 1){ 
                            include 'tokengenerate.php'; 
                            $token=generateRandomString();    
                            $update="update users set token='$token' where username='$username' AND password='$password'";    
                            $qr=$conn->query($update);
                            if($qr){

                               $sel="SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                               $query=$conn->query($sel);
                               while($row=$query->fetch_assoc(){
                                     $data[]=array(
                                     "name"->$row['username'],
                                     "token"->$row['token']
                                   );
                               echo json_encode($data);
                               }

                               } 
                }

            }
            else {
                header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Asked before... [Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: I try to do everything but not solution.

Comment: Post your angular code where you call this api please. The `No Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` error also occurs when using a wrong URL or a URL where the result is `404`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: try use install 'cordova-whiltelist-plugin' in client app and enable CORS in server. Cheer !

Answer (score 0):

This problem may result when you are making XmlHttpRequest from your domain to another and the browser is blocking because of cross origin for security purpose.

If you are not making request to another check if you are not making request from a non-secured url to a secured url e.g. A request from http url to https, this can also cause it.