# Ionic: Post File to Server

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I want to **post a JSON/CSV-file to the server and save it** in that location like other files I can manually put up there (with FileZilla for example) and read it out later from a different user.

I already tried using the **http.post** method like it is written [here](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/ionic3/posting-data-ionic-3-app-php-server/) but without success.

It would be great if someone could help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server to receive the data and save it to the disk.
You could use something like the [tutorial](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/ionic3/posting-data-ionic-3-app-php-server/) you followed.

The only thing that needs to be changed is that the php server should write the contents of your post request to the disk. Something like the script below

> I did not test this, so probably some changed need to be made.

```
<?php
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382740/cors-not-working-php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }


    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $request);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    else {
        echo "Not called properly!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will check it out!