# How can I make an HTTP POST request to my server, In my case I got error code 405 method not allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, http-post, ionic4

Tried So many Thins but Error is continuously persisting with the same error code 405 method not allowed

Below is my code. for auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http ,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

let apiUrl = " http://wiesoftware.com/greenchili/apisecure/login/";



var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Accept','application/x-www-for-urlencoded');




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(public http: Http ) { }

  userlogin(value){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      var headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl + 'loginUsers', value).subscribe(res => {
         resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Result that shows up error

```
General:-
Request URL: http://wiesoftware.com/greenchili/apisecure/login/loginUsers
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 43.255.154.38:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Header:-
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Request Header:-
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
```

I expect the request method to be POST but by default it always going as OPTIONS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my problem and problem is not at front end, It's the problem at back end php server.
to solve this we have to add some  code at server in api.php file.
code is below:-

```
<?php
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382740/cors-not-working-php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Proxy

1.First Create `proxy.conf.json` near Your package.json

```
{
    "/Your_API/1.0.0": {
       "target": "http://wiesoftware.com/greenchili/apisecure/login/",
       "changeOrigin": true,
       "secure": false,
       "logLevel": "debug"
     }
   }
```

2. anjular.json

"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },

3. in your base path

   ```
     protected basePath = './Your_API/1.0.0';
   ```

run and test

Comment: unable to understand 3rd step, can you please tell me what i have to do with 3rd step, Thankyou.

Comment: @ramkrishana its your Base path in service class

Comment: Its still not working ,same error occurring, I think this is the problem from server side related to local host:8100, seem server is blocking this origin.                           Anyways, Thanks for your help